# Xamarin iOS location with negative speed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager

The speed value which i get from the location object is always negative (-1). From Apples blog

```
A negative value indicates an invalid speed.
```

My code is

```
CLLocationManager  iPhoneLocationManager = new CLLocationManager ();
iPhoneLocationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization ();
iPhoneLocationManager.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
iPhoneLocationManager.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
iPhoneLocationManager.DistanceFilter = 5;
if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
            iPhoneLocationManager.StartUpdatingLocation ();
}
```

Even though it gives correct location, the speed is always negative.

Answer (score 0):

> Speed
>
> This [value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed) reflects the instantaneous speed of the device in the
>   direction of its current heading. A negative value indicates an
>   invalid speed. **Because the actual speed can change many times between
>   the delivery of subsequent location events, you should use this
>   property for informational purposes only.**

Unless you are constantly moving at a fairly constant rate directly away from the last sampling point, i.e. a linear vector based calculation and not running around in a tight circle, instantaneous speed is somewhat worthless. Now riding a bike and driving in a car at a constant velocity, instantaneous speed can be fairly valid...

Most `real-time` mobile mapping systems use some type of a speed sampling algorithm; i.e. distance moved over X samples using a moving average calculation divided by your sampling time interval is one way to get your 'current' speed.

Each app has a different use-case, so your algorithm would need to be adjusted, like if you have a hiking application and are showing the user his avg. speed on a trail and how long it will take to complete the trail would have a different algorithm from a public transportation app that calculates your arrival time based on current speed of the bus but factoring in traffic conditions, time of day, passenger stops, red lights, etc...

A blog post showing a simple sampling technique (in obj-c, but easy to translate his idea to c#): http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/